# Can I map a Ctrl + upper-case letter separately from Ctrl + lower-case letter?

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to figure out how to navigate windows little quicker, so I would like to map the following:

`:nmap <silent> <C-F> :wincmd f<CR>`

The problem is this remaps the `^f` (lower-case `f`) mapping, which is page down.  Is there any way to remap only `^F` (upper-case `F`) and leave the `^f` as it was?

Comment: You can if you use xterm or iterm and a recent Vim. See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23344/17449) for more info.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Mapping `<C-F>` (`Ctrl+letter`) is always the same as mapping `<C-f>` (`Ctrl+Shift+letter`). You can't map one without the other.

The root of the problem is that Vim reads characters from the terminal, which sends `^F` (ASCII code `0x06`) for both `Ctrl+f` and `Ctrl+Shift+f`; Vim has no way of knowing whether you pressed the Shift key. [This site provides some more information about terminals and control characters](https://bestasciitable.com/#context).

In theory, this *could* be done with gVim, since most (or all?) graphic environments send much more detailed key events. But unfortunately, gVim operates much like a terminal emulator, and can't distinguish between `<C-f>` and `<C-F>` either (this was perhaps a design decision for Vim-gVim compatibility).

---

Possible solutions:

- You could configure your terminal emulator to send a different code to Vim when you press `Ctrl+Shift+f`. For example, for xterm you could do:

  ```
  XTerm*VT100.translations: #override \n\
      Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>f: string(0x1b) string("[24;6~")\n\
      Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>r: string(0x1b) string("[23;6~")
  ```

  This will send the code for `<C-S-F12>` and `<C-S-F11>` to Vim, which you can pick up with:

  ```
  nnoremap <C-S-F12> :echo 'ctrl+F pressed!'<CR>
  nnoremap <C-S-F11> :echo 'ctrl+R pressed!'<CR>
  ```
- Note that you *can* map `Alt+Shift+letter`, since the terminal sends a different code for those: `<Esc>f` (`0x1b0x66`) or `<Esc>F` (`0x1b0x46`).
- NeoVim has, as far as I can find, not fixed this problem except for a few cases such as `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` and `Ctrl+Shift+Tab`, but it's possible that this feature will be added in the future.

Comment: Note, that recent versions of Vim support this in combination with recent real xterms using the modifyOtherKeys feature. See also `:h modifyOtherKeys` and https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5