# How do I map curly braces with Ctrl?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I want to map Ctrl + curly brace to some keystrokes.

```
imap <c-}> xxxx
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: How do you enter a `<c-}>` using your keyboard?

Comment: @muru, oh.. I got your point. I'm so stupid. Thank you very much. I need to press shift to get `}` hit.

Comment: Even then it might not work. See http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4290/205

Comment: @muru, no, it doesn't work!! so it's impossible to map <c-}> then??

Comment: I'd say so. Stick to `<c-]>`.