# Why is key mapping nnoremap <S-C-k> :w<CR> not working?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I'm trying to make it so I can write a buffer to disk with **one** keystroke.

**(Side note:** ideally, I'd like this to work in all modes, but for the moment as a start I'm just trying to get it to work in normal mode.**)**

On the Vim wiki it says...

> Vim supports representing control characters using symbolic notation like `<F1>`, `<C-W>`, `<C-S-F1>`, etc.

And also...

> A key with the `Ctrl` key modifier is represented using the `<C-key>` notation. For example `Ctrl-R` is represented using `<C-R>`. A key with the Shift key modifier is represented using the `<S-key>` notation. For example `Shift-F2` is represented using `<S-F2>`. A key with the `Alt` key modifier is represented using `<A-key>` or `<M-key>` notation. You can combine one or more key modifiers. For example, to represent `Ctrl+Shift+F3` you can use `<C-S-F3>`.

That seems to be saying that if I put this in my `.vimrc` it should work...

```
 nnoremap <S-C-k> :w<CR>
```

But it has no effect. When I reload `.vimrc` and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> no `[File] written` message appears in the bottom area.

I also tried this one but then <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> had no effect either...

```
 nnoremap <M-k> :w<CR>
```

No error messages.

I'm on OS X.

---

UPDATE

Ok I just tried this...

```
inoremap <M-s> Hey whats up
```

Then when I go into insert mode and press <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, Vim outputs...

```
ß
```

Is OS X intercepting my keystrokes before Vim even receives them? Is that why this isn't working?

If so, is there a way to make it stop doing that other than buying a different computer?

Comment: Note that mapping Control + Shift + key separate from Control + key doesn't work. See: [Can I map a Ctrl + upper-case letter separately from Ctrl + lower-case letter?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4290/51) (keys like F1 are special cases). That being said, the mapping looks fine. Which Vim are using? MacVim?

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I'll try using `<M>` instead of `<S-C>`. I'm not using MacVim. I'm using regular Vim 7.4.1129 installed via MacPorts.

Comment: If it can add some information I have `:nnoremap <S-C-f> :w<CR>` working fine on a Windows gVim 7.4 and a CentOS terminal vim 7.4 so maybe it comes from something in your setup.

Comment: [Also asked on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35850002/660921)

Comment: OS X will interpret Option-S as ß. To map it in Vim, you need to do `:inoremap ß Hey whats up`.

Comment: `<S-C-k>` is three keystrokes. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 1):

Your keyboard response can be different than you expect. For e.g. it can provide some special characters of your language.

To check out what your system does by pressing any combination:

`ctrl+v` in insert mode and then `option+k` or `alt+k`

Use the output symbol in your vimrc mapping instead of `<M-k>`

WARNING: this method is rough - symbols depend on system, terminal ect. So you have to put in your .vimrc conditions like:

```
if has("gui_running")
    if has("x11")
        <map_command_here>
    if has("gui_gtk2")
        <map_command_here>
```

or to detect systems (OS X) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842078/how-do-i-detect-os-x-in-my-vimrc-file-so-certain-configurations-will-only-appl)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `<C-S-k>`. It works fine for me. You can give some other key also, like `<F10>` for `:wq!`

```
:map <F10> :wq!<CR>
```

Comment: S-C-k also works for me in nnoremap mode.

Comment: Which OS and terminal?

Comment: Linux and vim 7.2