# How to map <C-i> separate from <Tab>?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to remap `<C-I>` to print markdown `*` symbol around the previous word. For example:

```
# user actions inside <...>
some text typed in vim insert mode<cursor_position> <C-I>

# expected  vim output
some text typed in vim insert *mode*<cursor_position>
```

I am using the following line in my `.vimrc` for remapping

```
inoremap <C-i> <ESC>Bi*<ESC>ea*
```

Problem is, as per help `:h i_CTRL-I`, `<C-I>` in insert mode is already mapped to something and the mapping above **doesn't** work for me. Pressing `<C-I>` in insert mode leaves a `<TAB>` on editor.

> `<Tab>` or CTRL-I Insert a tab.  If the 'expandtab' option is on, the
>                   equivalent number of spaces is inserted (use CTRL-V  to
>                   avoid the expansion; use CTRL-Q `<Tab>` if CTRL-V is mapped
>                   i_CTRL-Q).  See also the 'smarttab' option and
>                   ins-expandtab.

1. How do I make insert mode `<C-I>` mapping work?
2. How can I override global vim key-mapping with my own key-mapping defined in `.vimrc` file?

Comment: Very similar which explains some context: [Disable <Esc> but keep <C-[>](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3225/51). The short version is that Tab *is* ctrl+i. Perhaps there are workarounds specific for Tab, so not *quite* a duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

With a recent enough Vim binary, and for some terminals – including [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/) and [iterm2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/how-to-map-c-i-separate-from-tab/23344#comment46205_23344) if you enable the [`CSI u` option](https://iterm2.com/documentation-csiu.html) – Vim can distinguish `C-i` from `Tab`.

You need at least the Vim patch [8.1.2134](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2134).

And you may need to add these lines in your vimrc:

```
let &t_TI = "\<Esc>[>4;2m"
let &t_TE = "\<Esc>[>4;m"
```

Unless your Vim binary also includes the patch [8.1.2194](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2194), in which case it should have been done automatically if Vim has properly detected it's running in xterm.

---

As a simple test, run this shell command:

```
vim -Nu NONE +'nno <C-i> :echom "C-i was pressed"<cr>' +'nno <tab> :echom "Tab was pressed"<cr>'
```

Then press `Tab` followed by `C-i`.  The first keypress should log the message `Tab was pressed`, while the second one should log the message `C-i was pressed` (check out the output of `:messages` if you somehow missed the messages).

[image]

Make sure to install the `Tab` mapping *after* the `C-i` mapping; otherwise, the `Tab` mapping may be removed.

---

Vim can distinguish between many other keys; like `C-a` and `C-S-a`:

```
vim -Nu NONE +'nno <C-a> :echom "C-a was pressed"<cr>' +'nno <C-S-a> :echom "C-S-a was pressed"<cr>'
```

Here `C-` and `S-` stand for resp. the control and shift modifiers.

Or `A-b` and `A-C-b`:

```
vim -Nu NONE +'nno <A-b> :echom "A-b was pressed"<cr>' +'nno <A-C-b> :echom "A-C-b was pressed"<cr>'
```

Here `A-` stands for the Alt modifier.

---

For more info, see [`:h modifyOtherKeys`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#modifyOtherKeys).

Comment: This also works in iTerm2 by enabling the `CSI u` option https://iterm2.com/documentation-csiu.html

Comment: Actually now it seems to need the 'Control sequences can enable modifyOtherKeys mode' option from iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Keys

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://github.com/csdvrx/CuteVim/blob/15fed4e173121de20dfeed9983d5568ee00b7e8c/.vimrc#L283C1-L283C21), to have a custom mapping for `Tab` **and** still use `C-i` for going forward in the jump list, we need to have an explicit mapping for `C-i` as well: `nnoremap <C-i> <C-i>` and then, for example: `nmap <Tab> <c-^>`

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you cannot.

Long answer: `<C-i>` being equivalent to `<Tab>` isn't a vim quirk or builtin. It's a quirk of how terminals represent characters (cf. https://bestasciitable.com).

You simply cannot avoid this fact. Now, it may be possible to force your mapping to take precedence over the tab-behavior of inserting tabs/spaces, but I haven't done much investigating there. I would recommend choosing another mapping.