# In nvim, can I map Tab without removing <C-i> as `jump forward`?

Tags: neovim, terminal, iterm2

I've been mapping all my telescope commands to `tab-<key>`, which is quite convenient. However I've noticed that its broken the default shortcut for navigating forwards through the jump list, which is `<C-i>`.

Is there a way around this? Ive found similar questions like [How to map <C-i> separate from <Tab>?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/how-to-map-c-i-separate-from-tab) , but these are not nvim specific.

Comment: Just because it's not specific to neovim doesn't mean it won't work—did you try the linked question? The order of operations there appears to matter. Note also that mapping `<Tab>a` doesn't break `<Tab>`, but depending on your settings you may have to wait a few seconds before it takes effect (vim has to wait to know whether to trigger your mapping or if there's nothing else coming; alternately, `<Tab><some key that doesn't have a tab-mapping>` would happen faster, but you have to deal with the effects of the extra key—`<C-g>` might be a good option there.)

Comment: Ah, sorry I was ambiguous. I have tried the solutions suggested to that question, paying attention to the order of operations as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here was how I was able to achieve this.

```lua
-- Disable tab for jumping, must us <C-I> instead
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-I>", "<C-I>")
vim.keymap.set("n", "<Tab>", "<Nop>")
```

Details here https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/14090#issuecomment-1113090354