# Mapping to ctrl+m and ctrl+i in neovim

Tags: neovim, linux-ubuntu

I was trying to bind to `<C-m>` and `<C-i>` in nvim to move from window to but these seem to be mapped by zsh to newline and tab respectively. Is there any way to disable these mappings so I can use them for shortcuts?

Here's my nvim keymaps:
(The keys are in weird positions as I'm using colemak-dh)

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n" "<C-m>", "<C-W>h")
vim.keymap.set("n" "<C-n>", "<C-W>j")
vim.keymap.set("n" "<C-e>", "<C-W>k")
vim.keymap.set("n" "<C-i>", "<C-W>l")
```

I checked the keyboard shortcuts in the gnome-terminal gui but neither appear.

I tried disabling the shortcuts in zsh but this doesn't affect nvim.

Is there anywhere else I can look for keyboard shortcuts?

Thanks for any help

Edit:

When I run the command suggested in the comments:

```
vim -Nu NONE +'nno <C-i> :echom "C-i was pressed"<cr>' +'nno <tab> :echom "Tab was pressed"<cr>'
```

Both `<c-i>` and `tab` result in the same output of `Tab was Pressed`

I tried removing the newline action of `<c-m>` from zsh but this made `enter` no longer work and also didn't seem to affect nvim.

I switched to kitty which fixed my issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map <C-i> separate from <Tab>?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/how-to-map-c-i-separate-from-tab)

Comment: On some shell <Tab> it what the shell send to Nevim/Vim when the Ctrl-i key is hit. Maybe this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23344/23502) helps you to overcome the problem.

Comment: Typically not Shell, but OS/TERM-level

Comment: Have a look https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285208/how-to-remove-a-zsh-keybinding-if-i-dont-know-what-it-does#285210 You might need to remove the binding of it's set.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Maybe could you post it as an answer and accept it to make the question rest :-)

Comment: Not sure it should count as a proper solution as I didn't fix the problem, I just switched terminals. Does this matter? @VivianDeSmedt