# Is there a way to map (Alt - Shift - Control - Any key) in vimrc?

Tags: vimrc

The ergodox keyboard I use has two dedicated modifier keys ( Alt - Shift - Ctrl ) and
( Alt - Shift - Ctrl - Windows)

I would like to use the modifiers in my vimrc to do more specific tasks.

```
nnoremap <A-S-C-P> ihello
```

Was my initial test, it did not seem to work, however I didn't find too many example of multiple modifier keys in vim.

Is this possible/is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think this is related : [Can I map a Ctrl + upper-case letter separately from Ctrl + lower-case letter?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/can-i-map-a-ctrl-upper-case-letter-separately-from-ctrl-lower-case-letter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends:

- If this is terminal-bound Vim (i.e. the good old traditional way) then it will only work if the terminal type you're using has a way to encode multiple modifier keys when delivering them through [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) to Vim.

  [The most common sort of terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5802/138) can't do that, so chances are excellent that this is what's causing your symptom.
- GUI Vim front-ends will usually get you around this problem because the operating system's GUI layer *does* have a way to pass multiple modifier keys down to the GUI Vim front end, and it will pass them down to Vim.

  In this case, you can add a `if has("gui_running")` conditional around your `map` calls in your `.vimrc` file to create mappings intended to work only while under a GUI version of Vim. I will usually create an alternate mapping in the "else" clause so I have another way to get the same function.

Comment: I can do it in _xterm_

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ANSI X3.64 protocol -- of which the `xterm` protocols are descendants -- doesn't have a way to distinguish `S-A` from capital `A`. Thus the OP's problem. You might be able to define `C-A-A`, but not a distinct `C-A-S-A` that does something different.

Comment: I've mapped `<C-A-S-A>` to `:echo 1<CR>` and `<C-A-A>` to `:echo 2<CR>`. Got `1` and `2` respectively. I use XTerm(357)

Comment: That sounds like one of the extensions that xterm made over ANSI, then.