# Map C-S-[ and C-S-] to :tabprev and :tabnext

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to map `C-S-[` and `C-S-]` respectively to `:tabprev` and `tabnext`, but when I try that then I get "no lines in buffer".

A mapping like `C-S-tab` works. I looked through `:nmap` and didn't find an existing mapping. What am I missing?

Comment: This might be helpful: [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-debug-a-mapping)

Comment: I closed this as a dupe of the Q you mentioned in your answer, since that's what you indicated solved the problem. Note that this closure is *not a bad thing*—it may well help others find the answer to a similar problem! (and, since no else seems to have said it, welcome to [vi.se]!)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link in the comment by @statox♦ I was able to figure this out.
[This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723/21166) included a link to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4290/21166) where [the accepted answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4291/21166) explains that intercepting a `<C-f>` is equivalent to intercepting a `<C-F>` (technically `<C-S-f>`) in gvim, because:

> Vim reads characters from the terminal, which sends `^F` (ASCII code `0x06`) for both <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+f</kbd>; Vim has no way of knowing whether you pressed the Shift key.

The solution is to just map `C-[` and `C-]`, which works well for me.

Comment: Be careful though, `<c-[>` is an equivalent of `<esc>` and `<c-]>` is "Jump to the definition of the keyword under the cursor". You might want to use something else, e.g `<leader>]`.