# CTRL-SHIFT-P is not working on `neovim`

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

Below lines are part of my .vimrc.

```
map <C-S-p> :CtrlPCmdPalette<CR>  
let g:ctrlp_cmdpalette_execute = 1
```

It's working fine on normal vim,
but not working with `neovim`.

My neovim init file is correctly refer to .vimrc I think.

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim_runtime+=~/.vim_runtime/after  
let &packpath=&runtimepath  
source ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: The <C-S-p> is equivalent to <C-p>. You could checked how it is mapped using ``:verbose map <C-p>``

Comment: Thanks. @VivianDeSmedt

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: In my case, I couldn't get my telescope plugin to work because I had named my lua file `telescope.lua`. You need to name your files with names that don't conflict with the plugin's lua files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<C-S-p>` is equivalent to `<C-p>`.

You could checked how it is mapped using:

`:verbose map <C-p>`

It tells you to which sequence the `<C-p>` is mapped and which vim script is responsible.

Comment: Why is that equivalent? Can't I use 3 combinations like ctrl+shift+something, or ctrl+alt+something, alt+shift+something?

Comment: This is better explained in this post: [Can I map a Ctrl-Uppercase-Letter separately from a Ctrl-Lowercase-Letter](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/can-i-map-a-ctrl-upper-case-letter-separately-from-ctrl-lower-case-letter). In short it is true only for the letter mapping. e.g.: you can map differently ``<C-S-F5>`` and ``<C-F5>``. The reason is that, for historical reason, for the letters, the same code is sent to terminals.

Comment: that is not universally true anymore. Vim e.g. supports modifyOtherKeys, which does allow to distinguish those keys.

Comment: This is a pretty poor answer. Honestly. it doesn't even explain why or how to make Ctrl + Shift + p work. it just says "hurdur you're holding it wrong"

Comment: @airtonix, the definitive answer to this family of question do not exist yet. It depends on the OS, the executable console or GUI and the version and patch version of Neovim you are using. If it doesn't adresse your problem add more information and we will try to help you more specifically.