# Mapping <c-h> behaves like <c-s-h>

Tags: key-bindings

I am adding the basic config to mi vim

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-W>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-W>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-W>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-W>l
```

but I see the weird behavior that I must press Ctrl-Shift-{hjkl} for this to take effect ( it doesn't work without shift)

I can't figure out what causes this. Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I map a Ctrl + upper-case letter separately from Ctrl + lower-case letter?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/can-i-map-a-ctrl-upper-case-letter-separately-from-ctrl-lower-case-letter)

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). Depending on your terminal, terminal configuration and version of Vim this could be indeed not possible on some cases. Here another [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4291/23502) that give more details. Please read also the comment of @ChristianBrabandt that gives more information about recent developments.

Comment: Hi and thanks! I read the above, but its a bit different if i'm not mistaking. For me, I don't care if the version with shift will be mapped too. My problem is that it does not work without shift for some reason

Comment: Thanks. I read your question too fast :-| It works for me on gVim on Windows and Vim 9.0. Maybe could you share some information about your setup: OS, gVim vs. Vim? Did you try with a bare configuration of Vim?

Comment: Sure, I'm using vim 8.1 on linux ubunto, and my .vimrc doesm't contain any suspicious stuff as far as I can see. I thought that maybe `set ignorecases` could somehow impact, but it was not looking like this. I will try later to map other random command with ctrl and I will see if this behavior happens there too